# padding for element with more than 100% width

Tags: html, css

how to fix padding behavior for element with more than 100% width? indent on the right side of table collapses

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 150%;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr><th>sdsfd</th><th>sdsfd</th><th>sdsfd</th><th>sdsfd</th></tr>
    <tr><td>sdsdf</td><td>sdsdf</td><td>sdsdf</td><td>sdsdf</td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: can you be more clear and show us what you want to achieve

Comment: @TemaniAfif what exactly do you not understand?

Comment: nothing :) you have this layout which logic and there is no issue so what do you expect ? you want to have what ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif expected indent on the right side of table with variable width

Comment: you are simply expecting something illogical :) you are Overflowing the parent element so how you want the padding-right to be applied ? simply read more about how layout works ... when child element is bigger than its parent there is rules to follow and in your case this is what is happening so how you want a padding your are Overflowing to be applied ? so if the child element overflow the parent element did you expect that the background of the parent will cover all the child ? for sure no

Comment: @TemaniAfif with such deep understanding, have you any idea how to solve this?

Comment: `how to solve this?` --> am trying to convince you that there is nothing to solve :) simply because there is no issue and this is a normal behavior ... now you simply need to re-think about what you want ... if you want to have space in the right so simply add margin-right to your table equal to the padding-right you want at the beginning, but if you insist about the padding stuff you won't find any solution to a non-problem

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want a symmetric indentation, it doesn't matter how it will be implemented

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea using border instead of padding:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  padding: 30px 0;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 150%;
  border-right:30px solid #fff;
  border-left:30px solid #fff;
  position:relative;
}
table:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:15px;
  width:1px;
  background:#000;
}

table:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:15px;
  width:1px;
  background:#000;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr><th>sdsfd</th><th>sdsfd</th><th>sdsfd</th><th>sdsfd</th></tr>
    <tr><td>sdsdf</td><td>sdsdf</td><td>sdsdf</td><td>sdsdf</td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `150%` width is always gonna be relative to the `parent`'s width, so if the `parent` grows ( adding padding ) the `child` will grow accordingly and will end up outside because `50%` of the parent's width is bigger than the `padding` , you could do this by putting the `table` in a wrapper like :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  
}
#wrapper{  
  padding: 30px;
  width: 150%;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
  
  <table>
    <tr><th>sdsfd</th><th>sdsfd</th><th>sdsfd</th><th>sdsfd</th></tr>
    <tr><td>sdsdf</td><td>sdsdf</td><td>sdsdf</td><td>sdsdf</td></tr>
  </table>
  
  </div>
  
</body>
```

i don't know if this is what you're looking for but i hope it'll help :)

Comment: table is generated dynamically, width is not constant

Comment: if the `width` of the `table` is not constant then `width:auto` or even `width:100%` for both `table` and `wrapper` should do the trick , or maybe you should provide more details on your problem, like how the `table` is generated ? and where does `width : 150%` come from ?

Comment: 150% come from that is greater than 100%